# Scrapy keyerror and next page url not working

Tags: scrapy, keyerror

I am trying to **scrape** using this page as start url: https://www.imdb.com/lists/tt0237478?ref_=tt_rls_sm
This page has 3 lists and one of the lists has 100+ items.
My code **scrapes** only 100 items and not fetching data from next page. Please check what is wrong with the code.

```
import scrapy
from urllib.parse import urljoin
class lisTopSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name= 'ImdbListsSpider'
    allowed_domains = ['imdb.com']
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.imdb.com/lists/tt0237478'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        listsLinks = response.xpath('//div[2]/strong')
        for link in listsLinks:
            list_url = response.urljoin(link.xpath('.//a/@href').get())
            yield scrapy.Request(list_url, callback=self.parse_list, meta={'list_url': list_url})
        
        next_page_url = response.xpath('//a[@class="flat-button next-page "]/@href').get()
        if next_page_url is not None:
            next_page_url = response.urljoin(next_page_url)
            yield scrapy.Request(next_page_url, callback=self.parse)            
    
    def parse_list(self, response):
        list_url = response.meta['list_url']
        titles = response.xpath('//h3/a/@href').getall()

        next_page_url = response.xpath('//a[@class="flat-button lister-page-next next-page"]/@href').get()
        if next_page_url is not None:
            next_page_url = urljoin('https://www.imdb.com',next_page_url)
            print('here is next page url')
            print(next_page_url)
            yield scrapy.Request(next_page_url, callback=self.parse_list)  

        yield{
            'listurl': list_url,
            'titles': titles,
        }
```

Here is the error

```
2020-05-06 21:09:29 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET https://www.imdb.com/list/ls055923961/?page=2> (referer: https://www.imdb.com/list/ls055923961/)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python projects\scrapy\imdb_project\virenv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\defer.py", line 117, in iter_errback
    yield next(it)
  File "c:\python projects\scrapy\imdb_project\virenv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\python.py", line 345, in __next__   
    return next(self.data)
  File "c:\python projects\scrapy\imdb_project\virenv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\python.py", line 345, in __next__   
    return next(self.data)
  File "c:\python projects\scrapy\imdb_project\virenv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py", line 64, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "c:\python projects\scrapy\imdb_project\virenv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\offsite.py", line 29, in process_spider_output
    for x in result:
  File "c:\python projects\scrapy\imdb_project\virenv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py", line 64, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "c:\python projects\scrapy\imdb_project\virenv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\referer.py", line 338, in <genexpr>
    return (_set_referer(r) for r in result or ())
  File "c:\python projects\scrapy\imdb_project\virenv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py", line 64, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "c:\python projects\scrapy\imdb_project\virenv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\urllength.py", line 37, 
in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "c:\python projects\scrapy\imdb_project\virenv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py", line 64, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "c:\python projects\scrapy\imdb_project\virenv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\depth.py", line 58, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "c:\python projects\scrapy\imdb_project\virenv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py", line 64, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "C:\Python Projects\Scrapy\imdb_project\imdb_project\spiders\TopLists.py", line 29, in parse_list
    list_url = response.meta['list_url']
KeyError: 'list_url'
```

Comment: The error is on line 24. Remove list_url = response.meta['list_url'] and remove the list URL in the yield statement see if that fixes the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `Request.meta` to provide the `list_url` to your parse_list-method in your `parse-`method but you forgot to use it in your Request-call inside of parse_list for the next pages.
Simply add `meta={'list_url': list_url}` to your `Request` inside `parse_list` and it should work fine.

So the handling of next pages in parse_list should look like this:

```py
if next_page_url is not None:
    next_page_url = urljoin('https://www.imdb.com', next_page_url)
    yield scrapy.Request(next_page_url, callback=self.parse_list, meta={'list_url': list_url})
```

Btw: After Scrapy 1.7 the preferred way of handling user information is now `Request.cb_kwargs` ([see "Caution"-part in the official docu here](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#passing-additional-data-to-callback-functions))

Comment: I had certainly overlooked this thing. Adding meta to next page did the job but there is still a problem. Now I am getting first page results of 100 titles on line 1 while next page results appear on next line in csv. Is it possible to get first page and next page all results on same line in csv?